# Create toggle event in the expanded panel with angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

In this example I have angular material table combined with expanded panel. I can click and expand the row.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/keapqmllkjp?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts
What to change in that code in order to create a toggle event?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you referred your example from official document of Angular.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvokovdpnlx?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

And there are wrong source code on line 32 in "table-expandable-example.html".

Wrong:
(click)="expandedElement = element"

Correct:
(click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"